# elfutils-libelf-devel installed but not detected during VirtualBox install

Tags: fedora, software-installation, virtualbox, dnf

I am trying to install VirtualBox following [this tutorial](https://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2010/install-virtualbox-with-yum-on-fedora-centos-red-hat-rhel/).
I have done every steps but when trying to run :

```
/usr/lib/virtualbox/vboxdrv.sh setup
```

I get following output :

```
vboxdrv.sh: Stopping VirtualBox services.
vboxdrv.sh: Building VirtualBox kernel modules.
vboxdrv.sh: failed: Look at /var/log/vbox-install.log to find out what went wrong.
```

`/var/log/vbox-install.log` contains :

```
make V=1 CONFIG_MODULE_SIG= -C /lib/modules/4.16.16-200.fc27.x86_64/build SUBDIRS=/tmp/vbox.0 SRCROOT=/tmp/vbox.0 -j8 modules
make[1]: warning: -jN forced in submake: disabling jobserver mode.
Makefile:978: *** "Cannot generate ORC metadata for CONFIG_UNWINDER_ORC=y, please install libelf-dev, libelf-devel or elfutils-libelf-devel".  Stop.
make: *** [/tmp/vbox.0/Makefile.include.footer:101: vboxdrv] Error 2
```

So I have been trying to run `dnf install elfutils-libelf-devel`, but it is already installed :

```
Last metadata expiration check: 0:17:07 ago on Tue 26 Jun 2018 04:01:55 PM CEST.
Package elfutils-libelf-devel-0.170-10.fc27.x86_64 is already installed, skipping.
Dependencies resolved.
Nothing to do.
Complete!
```

Do any of you already ran into this issue or have an idea on how to fix it ?
Thanks guys !

edit :
I noticed it may be interesting to make sure `elfutils-libelf-devel` comes from the right repository, so output of `dnf info elfutils-libelf-devel` is :

```
Last metadata expiration check: 0:04:41 ago on Wed 04 Jul 2018 05:50:14 PM CEST.
Installed Packages
Name         : elfutils-libelf-devel
Version      : 0.170
Release      : 10.fc27
Arch         : i686
Size         : 32 k
Source       : elfutils-0.170-10.fc27.src.rpm
Repo         : @System
From repo    : updates
Summary      : Development support for libelf
URL          : http://elfutils.org/
License      : GPLv2+ or LGPLv3+
Description  : The elfutils-libelf-devel package contains the
             : libraries to create applications for handling
             : compiled objects.  libelf allows you to access the
             : internals of the ELF object file format, so you
             : can see the different sections of an ELF file.

Name         : elfutils-libelf-devel
Version      : 0.170
Release      : 10.fc27
Arch         : x86_64
Size         : 32 k
Source       : elfutils-0.170-10.fc27.src.rpm
Repo         : @System
From repo    : updates
Summary      : Development support for libelf
URL          : http://elfutils.org/
License      : GPLv2+ or LGPLv3+
Description  : The elfutils-libelf-devel package contains the
             : libraries to create applications for handling
             : compiled objects.  libelf allows you to access the
             : internals of the ELF object file format, so you
             : can see the different sections of an ELF file.
```